# How can I pattern match ID only making sure the variable number matches without having to hardcode all of the possibilities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, django, django-forms

I've recently become familiar with Jquery selectors....and they work great.  Starts with...ends with....

The problem I have currently is that all of my variable names essentially start with similar patterns and end with similar patterns.  This ID is generated from somewhere else so I'm hoping I can do something to use it effectively.

The pattern ID format essentially looks like...

```
   "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_october" 
   "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_november"
   "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_december"
```

I want to essentially matching on the set-* but only if it's identical to the other ids in my array.  Is this even possible without having to hard code anywhere from set-0 to set-1000?  Unfortunately the class for each one is the same as is the name situation.  Is there someway to say if the set numbers all match in a given array then add them up?  I can't use starts with or ends with in this case...and don't want to hardcode 1000 possibilities.  Thanks in advance for any ideas or thoughts.

I am trying to do something like.....

```
  function update_total()
  {
    var total = 0;
    $('.budget').each(function(index, element) {
     "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_october" + 
     "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_november" +
     "#id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_december"
        var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
        if( !isNaN( val )){
             total += val;
          }
        });
        $("#id_total").val(total);
  }
```

Here's a working solution........

```
  function update_total_total_total()
  {
    var ret = +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_january']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_february']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_march']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_april']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_may']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_june']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_july']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_august']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_september']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_october']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_november']").val() + +$("input[name$='set-0-line_item_december']").val();
    $("input[name$='set-0-line_item_total']").val(ret);
  }
```

But I could have up to 1000 different set values.  Is there some other way to do this without having to hard code this 999 more times?

This is a lot closer....but total still says 0.  It's updating all of the totals to 0...so that's progress but not getting the actual totals.  Forward progress thanks to Swati.

```
  function update_total_total_total() {
    //get length of input line_total for each sets..
    for (var i = 0; i < $("[name$=line_item_total]").length; i++) {
      var total = 0;
      //get all inputs but not line_item _total
      $(`input[name*=id_newbudgetlineitem_set-${i}-line_item]:not([name$=line_item_total]):not([name$=line_item_cost_center]):not([name$=line_item_description])`).each(function(index, element) {
         var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
        if( !isNaN( val )){
             total += val;
          }
      })
      $(`input[id$=set-${i}-line_item_total]`).val(total); //set value..of input
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could use a loop: `for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; ++i) {  /* \`set-${i}-*\` */ }`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  I'm a newb....to Jquery and Javascript anyway...can you please show me how I would incorporate this in my Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: I don't know what you do with these patterns. I just know how to generate them. You could provide a [mcve] of your code. You could show hardcoded examples for the first 2 possibilities.

Comment: I updated the example very crudely with what I am trying to do....I do know how to format if it starts with...ends with...but in this case I'm confused as to how I would go about get these IDs that all have the same set number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get length of total input whose name ends with `line_item_total` so this value will be counter for `for-loop`.

Then , inside for loop you can use `` $(`input[name*=id_newbudgetlineitem_set-${i}-line_item]:not([name$=line_item_total])`) `` this will fetch values from all inputs expect the `line_total_item` then add value on each iteration .

Lastly , use `` $(`input[name$=set-${i}-line_item_total]`).val(total); `` to set total inside `line_total_item` textbox.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function update_total_total_total() {
  //get length of input line_total for each sets..
  for (var i = 0; i < $("[name$=line_item_total]").length; i++) {
    var total = 0;
    //get all inputs but not line_item _total
    $(`input[name*=id_newbudgetlineitem_set-${i}-line_item]:not([name$=line_item_total]):not([name$=line_item_cost_center]):not([name$=line_item_description])`).each(function(i, element) {
      var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
      if (!isNaN(val)) {
        total += val;
      }
    })
    $(`input[name$=set-${i}-line_item_total]`).val(total); //set value..of input
  }
}
update_total_total_total()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  SET 0 :
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_october" value="5">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_november" value="51">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_december" value="15">
  <br/> Total :
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_total" value="" placeholder="total">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_cost_center">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-0-line_item_description">
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  SET 1
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_october" value="5">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_december" value="534">
  <br/> Total :
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_total" value="" placeholder="total">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_cost_center">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_description">
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  SET 2
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-2-line_item_december" value="4">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-2-line_item_oct" value="5">
  <br/> Total :
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-2-line_item_total" value="" placeholder="total">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-2-line_item_cost_center">
  <input type="text" name="id_newbudgetlineitem_set-2-line_item_description">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  This is getting me a lot closer.  The total is now updating kinda...it says 0...I can't seem to get it to recognize my input in the field.  I see your example is type="text" my type is numbers would that make a difference?

Comment: No , that should not cause any problem . But, check if name which i am using for inputs are same i.e : pattern ?

Comment: I have updated my example...it's closer but total is still 0.

Comment: Do ``console.log( $(`input[name*=id_newbudgetlineitem_set-${i}-line_item]:not([name$=line_item_total]).length)`` see what its giving you . Also , do `console.log(val)` inside loop see if it has any value or not .

Comment: I have added extra input ..which you are using as selector its working fine . I think something wrong with `name` on your end.. check if they are same or not .

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking up the initial loop.  Total is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233184/discussion-between-swati-and-steve-smith).

Answer (score 0):

This was the final working code.  As Swati suggested it was an incorrect name reference.

```
  function update_total_total_total() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $("[name$=line_item_total]").length; i++) {
      var total = 0;
      $(`input[name*=newbudgetlineitem_set-${i}-line_item]:not([name$=line_item_total]):not([name$=line_item_cost_center]):not([name$=line_item_description])`).each(function(i, element) {
        var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
        if( !isNaN( val )){
             total += val;
          }
      })
      $(`input[name$=set-${i}-line_item_total]`).val(total);
    }
  }
```